# To get particular integral of a 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is :-

$$(D^2-4)y=\cosh(2x-1)+3^x$$

I can handle the $\cosh$ function by reducing it to exponential form but how should I approach the function $3^x$?

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula that allows you to find a solution to $(D-\lambda)y=f(x)$. Consider that $$(D-\lambda)(e^{\lambda x}g(x))=\lambda e^{\lambda x}g(x)+e^{\lambda x}Dg-\lambda e^{\lambda x}g(x)=e^{\lambda x}Dg$$
So, if $(D-\lambda)y=f$, this implies $$f(x)=(D-\lambda)(e^{\lambda x}e^{-\lambda x}y(x))=e^{\lambda x}D(e^{-\lambda x}y(x))$$ integrating both sides $$e^{-\lambda t}y(t)=e^{-\lambda t_0}y(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t e^{-\lambda x}f(x)\,dx\\ y(t)=e^{\lambda(t-t_0)}y(t_0)+e^{\lambda t}\int_{t_0}^t e^{-\lambda x}f(x)\,dx$$

You can check directly that $g(x)=e^{\lambda x}\int_{x_0}^x e^{-\lambda s}f(s)\,ds$ actually solves $(D-\lambda) g=f$.

If you decompose $D^2-4=(D+2)(D-2)$ you can iterate the formula: once you have a $g$ such that $(D-2)g=f$, you want to find a $G$ such that $(D+2)G=g$...

That being said, formulas are as good as the algebra their users know, so perhaps it won't get you far, if you ignore that $\forall a>0,\ a^x=e^{x\ln a}$.